# Database default field not retrieved when using @Transactional

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2, spring-transactions

I have the following simple entity FileRegistry :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name = "file_store")
public class FileRegistry {

   @Id
   private String name;

  /**
   * Creation timestamp of the registry
   * This value is automatically set by database, so setter method
   * has been disabled
   */
   @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
   @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private LocalDateTime creationDate;
}
```

The following FileRepository DAO:

```
@Repository
public interface FileRepository extends JpaRepository<FileRegistry, String> { }
```

and the following Spring Boot test :

```
@SpringBootTest(classes=PersistTestConfig.class, properties = { "spring.config.name=application,db"})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Transactional
public class FileRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
FileRepository fileRepository;

@Test
void insertFileTest() {
    assertNotNull(fileRepository, "Error initializing File repository");

    // Check registry before insertion
    List<FileRegistry> allFiles = fileRepository.findAll();
    assertNotNull(allFiles, "Error retrieving files from registry");
    assertThat(allFiles.size(), is(0));

    // Insert file
    FileRegistry fileRegistry = new FileRegistry();
    fileRegistry.setName("Test");

    fileRepository.save(fileRegistry);

    // Check that the insertion was successful
    allFiles = fileRepository.findAll();
    assertNotNull(allFiles, "Error retrieving files from registry");
    assertThat(allFiles.size(), is(1));
    assertEquals("File registry name mismatch", "Test", allFiles.get(0).getName());

    System.out.println(allFiles.get(0));
  }
}
```

Persistence configuration class defined as follows :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories    
public class PersistTestConfig {
}
```

The table file_store defined in H2 as :

```sql
    CREATE TABLE file_store (name VARCHAR NOT NULL, creation_date TIMESTAMP(3) DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT file_store_pk PRIMARY KEY (name));
```

Everything works fine except that when I use `@Transactional` at test level (mainly to benefit from rollbacks i.e. db cleanup on each test) a null value is fetched for the creationDate field :

`FileRegistry(name=Test, creationDate=null)`

When I remove `@Transactional` from the test class, the fetched value contains the date as computed by H2 :

`FileRegistry(name=Test, creationDate=2019-03-07T17:08:13.392)`

I've tried to flush and merge manually the instance to no avail. To be honest, right now I'm a little bit lost on how `@Transactional` really works, in fact reading the docs and inspecting the code, the underlying `JpaRepository` implementation (`SimpleJpaRepository`) is annotated as `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`.

A little help on this subject would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.

Simply issuing a refresh `entityManager.refresh(allFiles.get(0));` solves the issue.

I tested also using Hibernate's `@Generated(INSERT)` specific [annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/generated/GeneratedValues.html#_legacy_support_in_database_generation) in the entity `creationDate` field and it also worked fine.

By the way I've eventually decided to drop this thing in favor of using Spring Data's JpaAuditing features and annotating the field with `@CreatedDate` annotation to fill the value instead of relying on DB date (by the way, production-wise, you probably shouldn't rely on DB time). To me this is feels more, let's say, "correct" and springy way of doing things.